# Как "сбросить" ненужные стили?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, iframe

Делаю встраиваемый `js` виджет, и проблема заключается в том, что стили страницы, на которую помещается `js` код, частично меняют внешний вид виджета.

То, как выглядит виджет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То, как выглядит в оригинале:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае, разница вызвана тем, что в первом случае, `html` имеет `font-size: 10px`, во втором же случае, это свойство не определено.
Если я выставлю `html font-size 15px`, то всё будет почти так же как в оригинале, но в этом случае, и размер шрифта на самой странице так же изменится.

Если же я весь виджет оберну каким-то дивом, и задам там `font-size: 15px !important`, то это повлияет не на все элементы, т.к. некоторые элементы изначально имеют свойство `font-size` со значениями в `rem` (как я понимаю, это % от данного свойства в `html`)

И получается, что нужно у каждого элемента задавать свойство вручную.
Но, помимо этого, увидел ещё и всякие `hover` и `focus` свойства, которые отличают оригинал от того, что создаётся при помощи `js` кода.

Каким образом я могу игнорировать все те стили, которые могут передаваться моему виджету от страницы, в которую он встраивается ?

Я подумал про `iframe` с собственным `body`, в котором этот виджет может быть размещён, но это не входило в изначальные планы.

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Пробовал использовать [YUI CSS Reset](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/), а именно, импортировать css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset-context/cssreset-context-min.css">
```

и повесить класс на обёртку:

```
<div id="widget-modal" class="yui3-cssreset"></div>
```

но в итоге, результат такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Примени к внешнему div-у виджета какой-нибудь из известных [css-reset](https://www.google.ru/search?q=css%20reset) вариантов. Ну или заверни виджет в отдельный див-обертку, и примени css-reset к обертке.